# Finding multiple (different) values under same ID SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I've got a student table which has

FirstName, Lastname, MisID and NetworkName. (MisID is username)

Theres an issue that students can potentially have two laptops (an older one) which is not allowed. How can I find when for example the userID occurs twice (therefore having two laptops)

This is my code so far but it just groups the entire MisID therefore making the count useless.

```
Select DISTINCT MisID, networkname FROM dbo.CompiledStudentData

GROUP BY MisID, networkname
HAVING COUNT(MisID) >= 2;
```

Cheers

Comment: What should be the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
select distinct MisID, networkname
FROM dbo.CompiledStudentData as t1
inner join
(
    Select MisID FROM dbo.CompiledStudentData
    GROUP BY MisID
    HAVING COUNT(distinct networkname) >= 2
) as t2
on (t1.MisID = t2.MisID)
order by 1, 2
```

the main idea here:

1. get list of students (MisID) who has at least 2 different network names (laptops), this is done by inner query (which creates temporary "table")
2. Join between original table (alias: t1) and this temporary one (alias: t2) gives us list of such students with all network names used

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly appreciate your help!

are you able to explain how that works? A little confused with the inner joining another select statement. Thanks

Comment: @AlexP2014 you can join 2 tables, right? select statement is basically table, so you can join table with select statement

Comment: yep, oh okay cool that makes sense. appreciate your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

`Select count(1) as cnt
, MisID
, networkname 
FROM dbo.CompiledStudentData
GROUP BY MisID, networkname`

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using window functions.  It seems like the easiest solution:

```
select sd.*
from (select sd.*, count(*) over (partition by msid) as cnt
      from dbo.CompiledStudentData
      ) sd
where cnt >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE adventureworksdw2008r2 

go 

SET nocount ON 

go 

/* 
Default 
*/ 
SET TRANSACTION isolation level READ committed 

go 

BEGIN TRAN 

IF Object_id('tempdb.dbo.#StudentData') IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
      DROP TABLE #studentdata 
  END 

CREATE TABLE #studentdata 
  ( 
     firstname   VARCHAR(50), 
     lastname    VARCHAR(50), 
     misid       VARCHAR(10), 
     networkname VARCHAR(100) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('John', 
            'Doe', 
            'jdoe', 
            'NET1') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Jane', 
            'Doe', 
            'jndoe', 
            'NET1') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Jack', 
            'Doe', 
            'jkdoe', 
            'NET1') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Jeff', 
            'Doe', 
            'jfdoe', 
            'NET1') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Jericho', 
            'Doe', 
            'jdoe', 
            'NET2') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Jeremy', 
            'Doe', 
            'jdoe', 
            'NET2') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Jill', 
            'Doe', 
            'jdoe', 
            'NET3') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('John', 
            'Schmoe', 
            'jschmoe', 
            'NET3') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Jane', 
            'Schmoe', 
            'jschmoe', 
            'NET3') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Jared', 
            'Schmoe', 
            'jschmoe', 
            'NET2') 

INSERT INTO #studentdata 
VALUES     ('Johnny', 
            'Schmoe', 
            'jschmoe', 
            'NET2') 

/* 
Find multiple occurance of MisID 
*/ 
SELECT Count(*), 
       misid 
FROM   #studentdata 
GROUP  BY misid 
HAVING Count(*) > 1 

/* 
Find user id exists more than once within a network 
*/ 
SELECT Count(*), 
       misid, 
       networkname 
FROM   #studentdata 
GROUP  BY misid, 
          networkname 
HAVING Count(*) > 1 

/* 
List user id that exit multiple times and all the networks to which it belongs 
*/ 
SELECT S1.misid, 
       networkname 
FROM   #studentdata S1 
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT misid 
             FROM   #studentdata 
             GROUP  BY misid 
             HAVING Count(misid) > 1) S2 
         ON S1.misid = S2.misid 
WHERE  S1.misid = S2.misid 
GROUP  BY S1.misid, 
          S1.networkname 

IF ( Xact_state() = 1 
     AND Error_state() = 0 ) 
  BEGIN 
      COMMIT TRAN 
  END 
ELSE IF ( @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ) 
  BEGIN 
      ROLLBACK TRAN 
  END
```